# Change query with the same name

Tags: excel, vba

I just started learning VBA and having some trouble making a macro to import from a folder with the same name.

I wanted to add "_current" or "_future" to the end of the folder name as its query name. Then have the data imported to specified columns in a specified workbook (let's say columns B-F in "worksheet 2").

I'm also not sure how to get the temporary ~$ files to not show in the query.

Any help would be appreciated!

```
ub Macro3()
'
' Macro3 Macro
'

'
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    ActiveWorkbook.Queries.Add Name:="Training 1", Formula:= _
        "let" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    Source = Folder.Files(""C:\Users\N14067\Documents\Training\VBA\Training 1"")," & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Split Column by Delimiter"" = Table.SplitColumn(Source, ""Name"", Splitter.SplitTextByDelimiter("" "", QuoteStyle.Csv), {""Name.1"", ""Name.2"", ""Name.3""})," & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Changed Type"" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#""Split Column by Delimiter"",{{""Name.1"", type text}, {""Na" & _
        "me.2"", type text}, {""Name.3"", type text}})," & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Reordered Columns"" = Table.ReorderColumns(#""Changed Type"",{""Content"", ""Name.2"", ""Name.1"", ""Name.3"", ""Extension"", ""Date accessed"", ""Date modified"", ""Date created"", ""Attributes"", ""Folder Path""})," & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Removed Columns"" = Table.RemoveColumns(#""Reordered Columns"",{""Content"", ""Name.2""," & _
        " ""Name.1"", ""Extension"", ""Date accessed"", ""Date modified"", ""Date created"", ""Attributes"", ""Folder Path""})" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "in" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Removed Columns"""
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Add
    With ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(SourceType:=0, Source:= _
        "OLEDB;Provider=Microsoft.Mashup.OleDb.1;Data Source=$Workbook$;Location=""Training 1"";Extended Properties=""""" _
        , Destination:=Range("$A$1")).QueryTable
        .CommandType = xlCmdSql
        .CommandText = Array("SELECT * FROM [Training 1]")
        .RowNumbers = False
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .BackgroundQuery = True
        .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
        .SavePassword = False
        .SaveData = True
        .AdjustColumnWidth = True
        .RefreshPeriod = 0
        .PreserveColumnInfo = True
        .ListObject.DisplayName = "Training_1"
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: I've figured out the temporary files section but still stuck on the naming/importing part.

Answer (score 0):

The value passed to `Formula` is just a String, so you can concatenate in a suffix for the folder.
FYI `Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10)` can be replaced with `vbCrLf`

Try something like this:

```vb
Sub Macro3()

    Dim suffix As String, wb As Workbook, ws As Worksheet
    
    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook 'always good to create a specific workbook reference
    
    suffix = "_current"  'for example
    
    wb.Queries.Add Name:="Training 1", Formula:= _
        "let" & vbLf & _
        "    Source = Folder.Files(""C:\Users\N14067\Documents\Training\VBA\Training 1" & suffix & """)," & vbCrLf & _
        "    #""Split Column by Delimiter"" = Table.SplitColumn(Source, ""Name"", " & _
        "Splitter.SplitTextByDelimiter("" "", QuoteStyle.Csv), {""Name.1"", ""Name.2"", ""Name.3""})," & vbCrLf & _
        "    #""Changed Type"" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#""Split Column by Delimiter""," & _
        "{{""Name.1"", type text}, {""Name.2"", type text}, {""Name.3"", type text}})," & vbCrLf & _
        "    #""Reordered Columns"" = Table.ReorderColumns(#""Changed Type"",{""Content"", ""Name.2""," & _
        " ""Name.1"", ""Name.3"", ""Extension"", ""Date accessed"", ""Date modified""," & _
        " ""Date created"", ""Attributes"", ""Folder Path""})," & vbCrLf & _
        "    #""Removed Columns"" = Table.RemoveColumns(#""Reordered Columns"",{""Content"", ""Name.2""," & _
        " ""Name.1"", ""Extension"", ""Date accessed"", ""Date modified"", ""Date created""," & _
        " ""Attributes"", ""Folder Path""})" & vbCrLf & _
        "in" & vbCrLf & _
        "    #""Removed Columns"""
    
    Set ws = wb.Worksheets("worksheet2") 'get a reference to the destination worksheet
    
    With ws.ListObjects.Add(SourceType:=0, Source:= _
            "OLEDB;Provider=Microsoft.Mashup.OleDb.1;" & _
            "Data Source=$Workbook$;Location=""Training 1"";Extended Properties=""""", _
            Destination:=ws.Range("$B$1")).QueryTable
        .CommandType = xlCmdSql
        .CommandText = Array("SELECT * FROM [Training 1]")
        .RowNumbers = False
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .BackgroundQuery = True
        .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
        .SavePassword = False
        .SaveData = True
        .AdjustColumnWidth = True
        .RefreshPeriod = 0
        .PreserveColumnInfo = True
        .ListObject.DisplayName = "Training_1"
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, I was able to solve my problem!